# Access container name in Nginx configuration file

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose

In Docker, I created a new network with `docker network create usta_network` command and referenced this network in service declaration in docker-compose.yml file.

It is okay, I'm able to ping services with container's name right now, but how can I reference a container's name inside Nginx Upstream declaretion? Which is best or better practice to bring access between containers ?

**docker.compose for nginx**

```
version: '2'

services:
   nginx-main:
      image: nginx:latest
      ports:
         - "80:80"
      volumes:
         - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
         - /var/log/nginx:/var/log/nginx
      container_name: nginx_main
networks:
   default:
      external:
         name: usta_network
./nginx.conf
```

**user  nginx;**

```
http {

    server {
       listen 80;
       index index.php index.html index.htm;
       server_name example.org www.example.org;

       location / {

         proxy_set_header Host               $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_pass http://rahmanusta_upstream;
       }
    }

    upstream rahmanusta_upstream {

      server rahmanusta_wp:6565;

    }
}
```

**docker-compose for mysql + wordpress**

```
version: '2'

services:
   mysql-db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
       MYSQL_DATABASE: mysql_db
       MYSQL_USER: root
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass
     container_name: mysql_db

   rahmanusta-wp:
     depends_on:
       - mysql-db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "6565:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: pass
     container_name: rahmanusta_wp
volumes:
    db_data:
networks:
   default:
      external:
         name: usta_network
```

**docker network inspect usta_network**

```
[
    {
        "Name": "usta_network",
        "Id": "b971429c1ddcfa791bdfff0a6f9463ab9cfb9ae04ba6a3aa60ce08ca11d0a5ab",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.20.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.20.0.1/16"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Containers": {
            "16cc89ca548fe90fb8ed9431d8e9633c341373344304ec3320acee1a81090709": {
                "Name": "rahmanusta_wp",
                "EndpointID": "d310cbf9617958226d36d5f9e0d804c113093097669b1d5ae8bed90d31dfca2f",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "5b0f7a7d95b23b6e69b17f85ebff5d652bdbcba305755169c6b9f78199fbf346": {
                "Name": "mysql_db",
                "EndpointID": "d2c304b450ce96d309ef51319aa42336bb742d99db095e98e129e547aee820c3",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "addf3c475fcfd5566b3d1c4b4a951f78978c07265211746f79711f38c5cd9649": {
                "Name": "nginx_main",
                "EndpointID": "3f4106184dbe805c509011c3dc42c673c85fcf2eb08441a5ecf24b9c5c68e2d4",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your docker-compose.yml, you'll name each of the services with their relevant name. Let's say I've created a jenkins instance behind my nginx docker container named jenkins1.

In my http section of the nginx.conf file I name the upstream server:

```
upstream jenkins {
  server jenkins1:8080;
}
```

In the server block then I can call this as below;

```
location / {
      proxy_pass https://jenkins;
    }
```

This will direct all traffic that hits your nginx container port to port 8080 on the jenkins1 service container.

**EDIT Based on updated question**

In your docker-compose.yml, use external links to link the two containers from outside the .yml file. Your nginx service section should read;

```
services:
   nginx-main:
      image: nginx:latest
      ports:
         - "80:80"
      volumes:
         - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
         - /var/log/nginx:/var/log/nginx
      external_links:
         - rahmanusta_wp
         - mysql_db
      container_name: nginx_main
```

Comment: I added my configuration files, but I couldn't connect to other container like your suggestion. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Are you able to ping the container hostname from your NGINX container or does it complain about unknown upstream host when you run it? Are you getting the NGINX landing page when you open port 80 on a browser?

Comment: @RahmanUsta can you also add the output from "docker network inspect usta_network" when you've the containers running?

Comment: Yes, It is pinging rahmanusta_wp container inside the nginx_main container. Btw, I added output from inspect command, it is above.

Comment: I don't know but it still doesn't connect, nginx gives 502 Bad Gateway

Comment: Ok, my solution would be to use one docker-compose.yml file and my solution with the container hostname will work. FYI, a 502 gateway with NGINX may be due to NGINX configuration. I think the docker config should work as is. See link : https://www.scalescale.com/tips/nginx/502-bad-gateway-error-using-nginx/#